# Does lp-e8 battery fits to canon eos 100d

Tags: canon, battery

I have my old camera - canon eos 650d with many batteries lp-e8 (7,2V, 1120mAh). I would like to buy a new canon eos 100d, but I've read in specification that it uses lp-e12 battery. Can I use lp-e8 batteries with canon eos 100d? I see that voltage is the same in both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't use the lp-e8 in an lp-e12 as the make of both the batteries is different. So even with the same voltage, they can't be used interchangeably because they wouldn't fit. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, the LP-E8 and LP-E12 batteries are different shapes and/or have the camera connection contacts in different places and are not interchangeable.

One of the nice things about Canon's upper tier series is that they often share a common battery over several successive models. The 5D, 6D, 7D, and x0D (60D, 70D, 80D) have all shared the same LP-E6 battery or its backwards/forwards compatible successor the LP-E6N since late 2008 with the introduction of the 5D Mark II that was the first model to use the LP-E6. The Canon 1-series has used the LP-E4 or its backwards/forwards compatible successors the LP-E4N and LP-E19 since early 2007 when the LP-E4 was introduced along with the 1D Mark III.

Not so with the Rebel/xx0D and xx00D series of EOS cameras. The BP-511/BP-512/BP-514, LP-E10, LP-E12, LP-E17, LP-E5, LP-E8, and NB-2LH have all been used with models in the Rebel line since the beginning of 2007. Other than the BP-511/BP-511A/BP-512/BP-514 series of batteries that are all the same form factor and voltage with varying total capacity and that are backwards/forwards compatible with each other to the best of my knowledge none of the other different batteries in the Rebel/xx0D and xx00D series of EOS cameras are interchangeable.